# $O$ is the center of a circle. If tangent $PQ= 12$ cm and $BQ=8$ cm, then chord $AB$ is,

Tags: geometry

[image]

I couldn't quite proceed very far on it when I stumbled upon $PQ^2=AQ.BQ$.

 But now I am stuck at proving it.
Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the power of the $Q$ with respect to the circle centred at $O$, which gives the following equality. Considering the similar triangles $\triangle BPQ$ and $\triangle PAQ$ (since $\angle BQP=\angle PQA$ and $\angle BPQ=\angle PAQ$) also gives this equality.

The triangles can be proven similar as:

$\angle PAQ=\frac{1}{2}\angle POB\\=\frac{1}{2}\left(180^\circ-\angle OPB-\angle OBP\right)\\=\frac{1}{2}\left(180^\circ-2\angle OPB\right)\quad\text{since }\triangle OPB\text{ is isosceles}\\=90^\circ-\angle OPB\\=\angle OPQ-\angle OPB\\=\angle BPQ$

The equation we derive from the above is:

$PQ^2=QA\times QB$

By plugging in the values,

$12^2=8QA$, hence $QA=18$.

Comment: How $\angle BPQ=\angle PAQ$?

Comment: From the fact that $PQ$ is tangent to the circle.

Comment: Still didn't get it, sorry.

Comment: @Aditya Agarwal Connect $OP$ then $OP\perp PQ$, $\angle BPQ=90^\circ-\angle OPB={1\over2}\angle POB=\angle PAB$.

Answer (score 0):

It is simple ...
 ( From the tangent property )

PQ²= AQ*BQ
(12)² = AQ*8
144/8=AQ
18=AQ 
SO, WE know that bq is already 8 ,then AB is 10

Comment: PLEASE use MathJaX formatting!